# Simplify the following sum on binomial numbers

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I need help to find out any way to get simplified the following binomial coefficients sum:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{b}{\binom{b+j-1}{b-j-1} \binom{b-j+a}{a}(-2)^{b-j}}$$

No clear idea on where to begin.

Comment: Have you computed the first few values?  If so, put them into OEIS and see if you get a match.

Comment: Already tried, thanks anyway @saulspatz!

Comment: Setting a=2 and varying b from 0 onwards one get {1,5,7,35,241...} with no results in OEIS. I suspect this expression can have a more simple form in terms of hypergeometric $1_F_2$ but not fluent on this tools enough to solve the problem.

Comment: On the other hand, if I set $b=2$ and let $a$ vary upward from $0$ I get $2, 8, 18, 32, 50, 72$ which looks nicely quadratic.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz. I also checked with $b=3$ and follows a cubic law as suggested your comment. But still no clue to get behaviour when fixing $a$ and moving along $b$ values.

Comment: I think the strategy must be to find the general formula for fixed $b$ for some small values of $b$ and hope to guess the formula for general $b$.  If that seems to be successful, try to to prove.  I'm going to play with it and see what I get.

Comment: When $b=3$ I get $2,0,-14,-48,-110,-208,...$ Is this what you get?  From your earlier comment it seems that your value for $a=2$ would be $35$, whereas I have $-14$.

Comment: Yes, it was. Correct series is {1,-6,18,-14,-126...}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hopeful about this.  I wrote a python script to generate the first few polynomials where we hold $b$ fixed and let $a$ vary.  In each case, I used sympy to interpolate a polynomial from the first $b+1$ values.  It then checks that this is gives a polynomial of degree $b$ and tests that the next $b$ values are indeed given by the polynomial.

```
from sympy import factorial as fact
from sympy import interpolate, poly
from sympy.abc import x

def choose(n,m):
    if n<0 or m<0:
        return 0
    return fact(n)//(fact(m)*fact(n-m))

def f(a,b):
    return sum(choose(b+j-1,b-j-1)*choose(b-j+a,a)*(-2)**(b-j) for j in range(b+1)) 

for b in range(1,10): 
    p=poly(interpolate({a:f(a, b) for a in range(b+1)}, x))
    assert p.degree() == b
    assert all(p(a)==f(a,b) for a in range(b+1,2*b))
    print(p.all_coeffs())
```

The output is given below for the the polynomials of degree $1$ through $9$, as a list of coefficients, leading coefficient first.

```
[-2, -2]
[2, 4, 2]
[-4/3, -2, 4/3, 2]
[2/3, -4/3, -44/3, -80/3, -14]
[-4/15, 8/3, 24, 202/3, 1204/15, 34]
[4/45, -32/15, -190/9, -236/3, -6524/45, -656/5, -46]
[-8/315, 52/45, 556/45, 476/9, 5104/45, 5398/45, 5276/105, 2]
[2/315, -152/315, -236/45, -944/45, -956/45, 4396/45, 109772/315, 14832/35, 178]
[-4/2835, 52/315, 1576/945, 16/5, -1064/27, -1524/5, -2817608/2835, -543238/315, -483964/315, -542]
```

It doesn't seem very encouraging.

Comment: Not really encouraging. Good work nevertheless. Thanks